# Goblin XNA -- Creating a labyrinth style game

Tags: c#, xna

Anyone know how to use Goblin XNA to implement ball control in the same way as one might find in the board game labyrinth?

There don't appear to be any tutorials or information at all regarding how to do this, despite there being a demo video displaying just such a thing.

I've setup the environment and gravity and added the ground and a sphere. I use WorldTransformation.Decompose to extract the current orientation of the board. I know the next step will be either ApplyLinearVelocity or AddForce to the sphere based on the current board orientation, but I don't know how to constantly apply these methods to the ball so that the ball is moving in response to the movement of the ball. Adding code to the Draw or Update methods only executes the code a single time. Anyone familiar with Goblin XNA at all and able to help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in Goblin XNA the Update and Draw methods are called the same way as standard XNA games. Can you give more specific information? source code perhaps?